# Can a browser-based HTTPS proxy secure browsing data while using a system-level proxy?

Tags: web-browser, proxy, browser-extensions

I use Nekoray to set up proxies for my Windows system.

When I connect to those proxies, does using a browser-based proxy with HTTPS encryption secure my transferred data through the web browser?

Can my ISP or the Nekoray proxies see the URL or other data transferred by that browser proxy?

Comment: @schroeder software I use is "Nekoray" which is a windows software to connect to different protocols like vmess,shadowsocks,trojan etc ,it has a VPN mode to tunnel the whole system, and some of the configs that I import to this software have no encryption. it's not a standalone VPN like Nordvpn but somehow it works the same way, also some android apps may use these unencrypted vmess/vless configs for providing VPN without informing users that the connection to these servers may not be encrypted

Comment: That's not a VPN ... it's just a program to help set up proxies. So, I'm going to rewrite this entire question, and then you might see how this answers itself.

Comment: @schroeder it's not about just Nokoray,Nekoray is one example I mentioned to answer your comment,it includes apps based on Nekoray and clash etc which use these configs as their connection because its open source,and in Android, it's mostly used as a VPN.I appreciate your last edits and comments because it was helpful, editing title was great in term of clarification too, but I think editing the question that way is not what I meant to ask

Comment: I edited based on your comment. If your comment is not what you meant to say, then you need to provide the detail I asked for. It sounds like you are not using a VPN at all, and that fact *needs* to be part of the question. What other "VPN that doesn't use encryption" are you talking about?

Comment: @schroeder just an edited version of these open-source clients that use predefined configs with zero or unknown encryption states in windows or Android.I used one of them on my phone recently(a friend of mine who sold VPN accounts with his edited version of v2rayn). but I got my answer from Steffen anyways and thanks again for helping to clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a HTTPS proxy extension secure browsing data while using an unsafe vpn?

In short: yes, for some meaning of "HTTPS proxy extension" and some meaning of "secure".

It is not fully clear to me what you mean with "HTTPS proxy extension". But modern browsers have the ability to use HTTPS to the proxy itself and thus provide encryption between the browser and the proxy. The "extension" you mention might just make use of this browsers ability, i.e. it just configures the browser to use a specific proxy. I assume in the following exactly this behavior.

A HTTPS proxy is similar to an encrypting VPN in that it creates a protected tunnel between the client and the proxy/VPN entry. It is also similar in that there is no added protection between the proxy/VPN exit and the server, i.e. it does not make server access itself secure. It is also similar in that one must trust the proxy/VPN provider the same way as one would trust the local ISP when no proxy/VPN is in use.

It is different in that the DNS lookup is done by the client system in case of a VPN, but by proxy in case of a HTTP/HTTPS proxy. It is also different in that the proxy configured in the browser only cares about traffic coming from the browser, but not about any other traffic from the client system which might be generated by other programs or by the OS itself (like software updates).

This also means that if you use the HTTPS proxy you no longer need to trust the underlying VPN - but only for traffic from the web browser. You need to trust the provider of the HTTPS proxy instead.

Comment: fyi - I rewrote the question based on new info provided